Save as feature when downloading files for users in NextJs
Users in my NextJs app should be able to download a pdf. I use S3 to store the pdfs and download them. That works fine. I was wondering if it's possible on modern browsers to "force" the "save as" window of the browser. In the context of my users, it would be useful to allow them to choose where to save them.
Current code:
// Handle PDF Download
    const handleDownload = async (request) => {
        // Set loading state for this request
        setLoadingRequests((prev) => ({ ...prev, [request._id]: true }));

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/solicitud/download_pdf', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                credentials: 'include',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    requestId: request._id,
                    tipo: request.tipo,
                }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                console.error('Failed to download PDF:', errorData.message);
                alert(`Error: ${errorData.message || 'Failed to download PDF'}`);
                return;
            }

            const blob = await response.blob();
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', `${request._id}.pdf`);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
            alert('Ocurrió un error inesperado al descargar el PDF.');
        } finally {
            // Reset loading state for this request
            setLoadingRequests((prev) => ({ ...prev, [request._id]: false }));
        }
    };

The frontend button that the user clicks:
{/* Action Buttons */}
                                    <div className="w-full flex justify-end md:w-auto mt-4 md:mt-0">
                                        {request.estado.startsWith('Completado') ? (
                                            <button
                                                onClick={() => handleDownload(request)}
                                                className={`flex items-center justify-center bg-storm-50 border-2 ${loadingRequests[request._id] ? 'border-transparent' : 'border-transparent hover:border-storm-500'
                                                    } text-storm-500 px-4 py-1 mr-2 rounded-lg shadow`}
                                                disabled={loadingRequests[request._id]}
                                                style={{ minWidth: '80px' }} // Ensures consistent width
                                            >
                                                {loadingRequests[request._id] ? (
                                                    <l-dot-stream
                                                        size="50" // Adjusted size for better fit
                                                        speed="2.0"
                                                        color="orange"
                                                    ></l-dot-stream>
                                                ) : (
                                                    <>
                                                        <i className='fa fa-download' aria-hidden="true" title="Download PDF"></i>
                                                        <span className="ml-2">PDF</span>
                                                    </>
                                                )}
                                            </button>

                                        ) : (
                                            <button
                                                className="flex items-center justify-center bg-storm-50 border-2 border-transparent text-storm-300 px-4 py-1 mr-2 rounded-lg shadow hover:cursor-not-allowed"
                                                disabled={true}
                                                style={{ minWidth: '80px' }} // Ensures consistent width
                                            >
                                                <i className='fa fa-download' aria-hidden="true" title="Download PDF"></i>
                                                <span className="ml-2">PDF</span>
                                            </button>
                                        )}

